# handling same touch event with multiple control (parent and child)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I need to handle a touch event on my custom uiviewcotroller. I have a sub controller within the view that already handle touch event (it's a plot that handle zooming and scrolling).
I want to make a tabbar disappear when I tap the screen once. Actually it only works (even tought the tabbar doesn fade away but simply is no visible) in the areas in which the subcontrol is not present but I need it to work everywhere still handling the subcontrol events.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set userInteractionEnabled = NO in subcontrol view.

**UPD:** Try to add transparent button to subcontrol.

Comment: That would make it impossible to handle touch event on the subcontrol, that is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling the superclass's event handler method in your event handler method to continue propagation of the event up the responder chain.

Also make sure the subcontrol's `exclusiveTouch` property is set to `NO`.

You might want to have a look at the [event handling documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9)